# Find whether a number is greater or not

Tags: javascript, syntax, comparison

I want to test whether a request parameter is greater then 12 or not  JavaScript.

It always gives the alert "lesser" even when I change the value of q to 12.

The current URL is: `www.test.com?id=2`

How can this be done in JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean it always returns false? You are not returning anything, you are `alert`ing text.

Comment: Your title and question are opposite.  One asks for greater, one asks for less than.  Your code tests if q is greater than 10.

Comment: You code looks like it should work to me.  What problems are you seeing?

Comment: What's the issue here?  http://jsfiddle.net/pfQ9D/

Comment: Resisting the urge to post a jQuery solution just for the lulz...

Comment: `window.location.search.substring(1)` will return `id=2` not `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. If it returns true, then it alerts greater. Although you should be adding semicolons at the end of statements. Your code would look like this:

```
var q = 14;
if (q > 10)
    alert('greater');
else
    alert('Lesser');
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gn8Ej/)

As said by Derek, if q === 10, then it would alert 'Lesser' because 10 is not more than 10.

EDIT: Here, you have 2 options. Either use something like PHP to make q equal to the number like this:

```
q = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

Note that using this would open your site up to all kinds of XSS, so if you decide to go this way, learn a bit about security, and don't rush into uploading it to a live website.

Or, if you want to to do it using JavaScript only, then do it like this:

```
q = location.href.substring(location.href.indexOf('id=')+3); //3 is the length of id=
q = parseInt(q, 10); //With substring, you get a string, so you have to parse it
```

The 10 is the radix parameter, avoiding you getting strange numbers for inputs such as 010 (would be 8 without the parameter).

Comment: @Amaan.I am getting the value of q from the request parameters.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine to me. You might want to include semi-colons after the alerts to be on the safe side. Also, your test does not account for 'equal to', so 10 will report "lesser" when in fact it is equal to.